# Wait for JQuery execution until whole page is loaded breaks execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a JQuery script to load a newsletter subscription popup window after the users scrolls down a certain amount of pixels using the jQuery .scroll/.scrollTop function.

At the moment it's all encapsulated within

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
```

The problem is the usual caching and images issue and the subscription box pops up all over the place. I was reading about delaying jQuery using the .load function until the page is fully loaded. However when I replace

```
jQuery(document).ready
```

with

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){
  //your code here
});
```

the functionality breaks completely.

I want to note that I am using WordPress and have the script enqueued like this:

```
function enfold_child_custom_scripts(){

    // Register and Enqueue a Script
    // get_stylesheet_directory_uri will look up child theme location
    wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enfold_child_custom_scripts');
```

Here is my JS/jQuery code as it is right now.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    jQuery("#nl-pop").hide(); //hide nl block initially
    var disableFade = "false";

    var startShowTop = jQuery("#newsletter-cta").offset().top - 3500;
    var startHide = jQuery("#newsletter-cta").offset().top - jQuery(window).height(); //Hide when the viewport is reached

    jQuery('#no-thanks').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         jQuery('#nl-pop').fadeOut('slow');
         disableFade = "true";
    }); 
 jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() < (startShowTop) ) //when scrollposition is smaller than the first point
        {
             jQuery("#nl-pop").fadeOut(200); // Hide when in the upper part of the page
        }
        else //when reached the lower part of the page
        {
            if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > startShowTop && $(window).scrollTop() < startHide && disableFade==="false") { //When reached the show position but not as far down as the hide position
                jQuery("#nl-pop").fadeIn(200); //show
            }

            else if(jQuery(window).scrollTop() > (startHide) ) { //scrolled down to the bottom newsletter box
                jQuery("#nl-pop").fadeOut(200); //hide
            }
        } 

    });   
});
```

Comment: You already passed `$` into the `ready` statement. It's safe to use `$` in place of `jQuery` inside the `ready` block.

Comment: **Note:** for your function `enfold_child_custom_scripts()`, you don't need to use anymore **wp_register_script()** because now it's merged in **wp_enqueue_script()**. You can replace both lines with only one: `wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery'));` [**Codex reference - wp_enqueue_script()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Answer (score 0):

Move the calculation of `startShowTop` and `startHide` to be inside of `.scroll()`. That way their value won't suffer from unloaded elements. They will instead be dependent on the current state of the page (which will most likely be after entire page has loaded).